# How to Get Checkbox values in PHP using FOR loop only

Tags: php, html, for-loop, checkbox, foreach

Currently following code is working fine But I want an alternative code other than foreach loop,

```
 <form action="action_page.php" method="post">

        Select skills
        PHP
        <input type="checkbox" value="PHP" name="skills[]">
        JAVA
        <input type="checkbox" value="Java" name="skills[]">
        <input type="submit" value="submit">
    </form>

<?php

$skills=$_POST['skills'];
foreach($skills as $value){
    echo $value;
};
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$skills=$_POST['skills'];
for($i=0; $i<sizeof($skills);$i++){

echo $skills[$i];

};
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as an answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are generally of higher quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following

```
if(!empty($skills)) {
  for($i=0; $i < count($skills); $i++) {
     echo $skills[$i];
  }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative solution without foreach would be to use the php function  `implode()`.

Like that:

```
if(! empty($skills)) {
    $skills_to_str = implode("/", $skills);
}
```

The function `implode()` spread the  `$skills`  array into a string `$skills_to_string` and separates each value with "/".