# How to process HTML checkbox from form via PHP?

Tags: php, html

I'm trying to parse an HTML checkbox question into various booleans for each option.

The form is getting passed via POST. The question needs to be required in the final version, but I currently am not enforcing that. I need the variable for each question to be initialized at the end for the create function call that follows.

I tried parsing each checkbox separately through the args array, through the POST array, and by saving the checkbox results to an array.

```
<main class="family-account-form">
    <form class="family-account-form" method="post">
    <label><em>* </em>What services are you interested in?</label>
            <p> This is not a guarentee of services. Service is dependent upon volunteer availability. </p>
            
            <input type="checkbox" id="meals" name="services[]" value='meals'>
            <label> Meals </label> 
            
            <input type="checkbox" id="lawncare" name="services[]" value="lawncare">
            <label> Lawn Care </label> 
            
            <input type="checkbox" id="housecleaning" name="services[]" value="housecleaning">
            <label> Professional House Cleaning</label>
<!--- Checkbox code for second two parsing methods
<input type="checkbox" id="meals" name="meals" value='meals'>
            <label> Meals </label> 
            
            <input type="checkbox" id="lawncare" name="lawncare" value="lawncare">
            <label> Lawn Care </label> 
            
            <input type="checkbox" id="housecleaning" name="housecleaning" value="housecleaning">
            <label> Professional House Cleaning</label> -->

            <input type="submit" name="registration-form" value="Submit">
    </form>
```

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test | Form </title>
</head>

<body>
    <?php
        if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
            $args = $_POST;

            $services=$args['services'];
            if(empty($services)){
                $meals=0;
                $housecleaning=0;
                $lawncare=0;
            }
            else{
                $n=count($services);
                //echo $n . "number of services[] items";
                for($i=0;$i<$n;$i++){
                    switch ($services[$i]){
                        case 'meals':
                            $meals=1;
                        case 'lawncare':
                            $lawncare=1;
                        case 'housecleaning':
                            $housecleaning=1;
                    }
                }
            }
            echo "after switch statement:<br>";
            echo "meals: ". $meals."<br>";
            echo "housecleaning: ". $housecleaning."<br>";
            echo "lawncare: ". $lawncare."<br>";

            if($args['meals']){
                $meals=1;
            }
            else{
                $meals=0;
            }

            if($args['lawncare']){
                $lawncare=1;
            }
            else{
                $lawncare=0;
            }

            if($args['housecleaning']){
                $housecleaning=1;
            }
            else{
                $housecleaning=0;
            }
            echo "after args[]:<br>";
            echo "meals: ". $meals."<br>";
            echo "housecleaning: ". $housecleaning."<br>";
            echo "lawncare: ". $lawncare."<br>";

            if(isset($_POST['meals'])){
                $meals=1;
            }
            else{
                $meals=0;
            }
            if(isset($_POST['housecleaning'])){
                $housecleaning=1;
            }
            else{
                $housecleaning=0;
            }
            if(isset($_POST['lawncare'])){
                $lawncare=1;
            }
            else{
                $lawncare=0;
            }
            echo "after POST array:<br>";
            echo "meals: ". $meals."<br>";
            echo "housecleaning: ". $housecleaning."<br>";
            echo "lawncare: ". $lawncare."<br>";
        }
        else {
                require_once('example.php'); 
        }
        ?>
        <?php
            echo "end of code:<br>";
            echo "meals: ". $meals."<br>";
            echo "housecleaning: ". $housecleaning."<br>";
            echo "lawncare: ". $lawncare."<br>";
        ?>
</body>
</html>
```

The switch statement results in all the variables being set to 1. The args array results in all the variables being set to 0, as does the POST array. The print statements are also throwing "undefined array key" warnings. I'd prefer to have all variables initialized to avoid those warnings from appearing.

I did try adding value attributes to the html question but it does not seem to have changed anything. I could not tell what the difference between the name and value attributes are. The base code I'm working from does not use value attributes for it's checkbox question.

How do I processes the checkbox question?

Comment: [Getting checkbox values on submit](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18421988/2943403) and [How to Get Checkbox values in PHP using FOR loop only](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60575084/2943403) and [Get $_POST from multiple checkboxes](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4997252/2943403)

Answer (score 0):

Please note that the data of a checkbox, **if not checked**, will not be submitted, so if you rely solely on `services[]` to process the submitted values (as array) for respective items , you will get into problems (actually cannot know which ones are checked and which ones are not)

From your code (if I understand your purpose correctly), you just want to know which checkboxes are checked (and not), since the choices are pre-defined (you only have the following):

```
Meal
Lawncare
Housecleaning
```

Then , we may use the following simple form

```
<form action=testx2.php method=POST>
<input type=checkbox name=services[0] value="on">Meal <br>
<input type=checkbox name=services[1] value="on">Lawncare<br>
<input type=checkbox name=services[2] value="on">Housecleaning<br>
<input type=submit>
</form>
```

and on submission, use the following (testx2.php) to check the submission:

```
<?php

$servicetype=array("Meal","Lawncare","Housecleaning");

$n=3;

for($i=0;$i<$n;$i++){

  if ($_POST["services"][$i]=='on'){
    echo $servicetype[$i]. " is on<br>";
    } else {
    echo $servicetype[$i]. " is not on<br>";
  }

}
?>
```

Note: I have intentionally used the `for($i=0;$i<$n;$i++){ }` which you have used in your original code, but other people may use other looping structure.

Comment: Although a considerate refactor, I believe the asker's problem was regarding missing `break` statements. "_The switch statement results in all the variables being set to 1._"